# No navigation for sforce.one.navigateToURL from vfpage lightning out in a community site

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-community, lightning-out

I have a lightning component developed to work both in lightning and in community pages(`flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`)

To work around LockerService limitations the component performs navigation to a vfpage in order to load a remote js library. Apart from that the vfpage exposes the same lightning component through lightning out option.

In the vfpage I have implemented a few handlers like `force:navigateToURL` for example to make sure everything continues to work.

```
           $A.eventService.addHandler({
              event: "force:navigateToURL",
              handler: function(event) {
                if (window.hasOwnProperty("sforce") && sforce.one) {
                  // VF page in S1 or Lightning Exp
                  sforce.one.navigateToURL(event.getParam("url"));
                } else {
                  // VF page in Classic
                  console.log("force:navigateToURL is unimplemented");
                }
              }
            });
```

So when a link from the lightning component is fired the vfpage is able to handle it. At this point everything works as expected. In my case the `navigateToURL` is used to jump to another record while reloading the same vfpage and carrying a record id in the query string along with a few other params.

Now, the component works **almost** the same when dropped in a community site. I say almost because from Lightning I am able to navigate to the vfpage, every feature of the component is working but `navigateToURL` is not. I debugged the call, I can see that `sforce.one.navigateToURL(event.getParam("url"))` is actually invoked (`event.getParam("url")` contains the correct URL, only the path actually, so `/apex/pagename?query...`) but no navigation is performed and no error is logged in the JavaScript console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be because of the community URL being different from the SF Org URL?

Comment: I don't know how that would come into play actually. There's another function I actually use - `navigateToSObject` - that brings me back to the community lightning record page and that just works. I'm clueless.